# Extract substring by regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract a resource id using regex into a variable.

So far I managed to match the string, but I'm confused as to how to extract the digits into a separate value.

```
"/posts/23/edit".match(/\/posts\/(\d*)\/edit/g)
// => ["/posts/23/edit"]
```

Comment: Check SO Docs [Javascript Regex Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/242/regular-expressions/13491/regexp-groups)

Comment: Removing the `/g` gives you the digits in the second element in the resulting array. Any particular reason you put it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\/posts\/(\d*)\/edit/g.exec("/posts/23/edit")
// => ["/posts/23/edit", "23"]
```

Comment: The answer itself could use an explanation…

Comment: (I didn't do any downvotes, but a bit of an explanation wouldn't hurt to teach the guy *why* not only *how*)

Comment: @Biffen I'm confused. How does that constitute a downvote? The code is as self-explanatory as it gets.

Comment: @Biffen Actually, I expect the OP do do some reading on their own. Really. This is a *basic* problem. The terseness of the answer testifies this. Flipping through the docs of `RegExp#exec` is actually necessary if you didn't know it before. Why would I have to write an excerpt of the documentation?

Comment: @ave I figured you are just missing a basic hint here and would be fine on your own after that.

Comment: @Tomalak It's not that self-explanatory, IMHO. And it deserves a downvote partly for what *ppeterka* mentioned, and partly because ‘code dump’ answers make it seem like it's OK to use SO as a code-writing service. (Again; IMHO (which is what dictates my voting).)

Comment: Well if it's not that self-explanatory to take an almost-correct one-liner the OP gave and turn it into a correct one-liner that looks almost exactly like it, then I don't know what would be self-explanatory. It does not get more basic than that. And correcting one line of code really is a long shot from "code writing service". Besides, we are not a documentation summer-upper service, either, a lot of people tend to forget that.

Comment: For those who would like to read more about this method, a good place to start is: [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) at **MDN**.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use the `g` (global) flag, which makes `match` ignore capturing groups.

If you are only interested in the first match, just remove the flag.

```js
console.log("/posts/23/edit".match(/\/posts\/(\d*)\/edit/));
// [ "/posts/23/edit", "23" ]
```

Otherwise you should keep the flag and repeatedly call `exec` inside a loop.

```js
var match, rg = /posts\/(\d*)\/edit/g;
while(match = rg.exec("/posts/23/edit -- /posts/24/edit")) {
  console.log(match);
}
```